# How to proof the existence of the nth-roots using the Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Given $y>0$ prove that $\exists\, x>0$ such that $x^n$ = $y$.

We have to find $b>0$ such that $b^n$ > $y$.

We have 3 cases:

1) $y>1$

We have that $y^n>y$, so we can set $b=y$.

2) $y<1$

Let's set $b=1$.

3) $y=1$

This is simply $x=1$.

The function $f(x) = x^n$, $f:[0,b] \rightarrow ℝ$ accomplishes the Intermediate Value Theorem, i.e, $\exists\, x \in (0,b)$ such that $f(x)= y$.

Is that right?

Comment: I think you may have a circular problem.  We must assume $f(x) = x^n$ is a continuous function.  To prove that we must do a delta epsilon proof and to do that you must assume $n$ th roots are well defined.

Comment: What I am trying to check is if I have to say the other case where b<0

Comment: Use $0^n = 0 < y$ and if $y < 1$ then $1^n = 1 > y$.  If $y = 1$ then $1^n = y$ and $1$ is the root.  if $y > 1$ then $y^n > y$.

Comment: You don't have to check $b < 0$ because $a= 0 \ge 0$.  And you have $a^n = 0^n = 0 < y$.  So know you need $b > 0$ and $b^n > y$.  So *assuming $x^n$ is continuous* (not sure how you are supposed to assume that) then there is a $c \in [a,b]$ so that $c^n = y$.

Comment: @fleablood:  $\vert x_2^n - x_1^n \vert = \vert (x_2 - x_2)(x_2^{n - 1} + x_2^{n -2} x_1 + \ldots + x_1^{n - 1}) \vert =\vert x_2 - x_1 \vert \vert x_2^{n - 1} + x_2^{n -2} x_1 + \ldots + x_1^{n - 1} \vert \le M \vert x_2 - x_1 \vert$ where we may take $M > n z^{n - 1}$ for any $z$ with $x_1, x_2 < z$.  This shows $x_2^n \to x_1^n$ as $x_2 \to x_1$ without resorting to establishing $y^{1/n}$ is continuous

Comment: @fleablood: if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous then so is $x \mapsto f(x)g(x)$ (by an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument that doesn't involve the continuity of $x \mapsto x^n$). As $x \mapsto 1$ and $x \mapsto x$ are both continuous then so is $x \mapsto x^n$ for any $n \in \Bbb{N}$ (by an easy induction on $n$).

Comment: @RobArthan good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is more or less correct.

If $a = 0$ then $a^n = 0 < y$.

If $y < 1$ and if $b = 1$ then $b^n = 1 > y$

If $y > 1$ and if $b = y$ then $b^n = y^n > y$.

If $y = 1$ then .... well we could simply do $b = 2$ and $2^n > 1 = y$... or we could simply point out $1^n = y$ so that is the $n$-th root we want.

So any event you have $a^n < y < b^n$ so by intermediate value theorem there is a $c \in [a,b]$ so that $c^n = y$.

...

However that makes me very uneasy because we must *assume* $f(x) = x^n$ is a continuous function.

Answer (score 0):

It appears safe to assume $1 \le n \in \Bbb N$, the natural numbers.

If we grant that $f(x) = x^n$ *is* in fact continuous, then it is but a short step, *via* the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), to see that $n$-th roots must exist:

Let $y > 0$.  Clearly,

$f(0) = 0^n = 0 < y; \tag 1$

also,

$f(1 + y) = (1 + y)^n = 1^n + n \cdot 1^{n - 1} y + \dfrac{n!}{2!(n - 2)!} 1^{n -2} y^2 + \ldots + y^n$
$= 1 + n y + \ldots + y^n = y + 1 + (n - 1)y + \ldots + y^n > y + c, \tag 2$

with $c = 1 + (n - 1)y + \ldots + y^n > 0$; hence

$f(1 + y) > y; \tag 3$

we thus have

$0 = f(0) < y < f(1 + y), \tag 4$

and it now follows from the IVT that there is an $x \in (0, 1 + y)$ with

$y = f(x) = x^n, \tag 5$

and we are done!

Done, that is, except for need to address the continuity of $f(x) = x^n$.  I would ordinarily feel it is safe to assume this as well, but since fleablood expressed concern that this fact be demonstrated, I offer the following:

If one accepts the use of a little elementary calculus, i.e. that

$f'(x) = nx^{n - 1}, \tag 6$

then since continuity follows from differentiability, then we may rest here.  However, the logical question as to how we know $f(x)$ is differentiable and that (6) binds lingers on; of course, an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument is the most obvious way to address this issue.  One can also side with Rob Arthan, who mentioned in his comment to the question itself that the continuity of $f(x) = x^n$ follows from the continuity of a product of continuous functions; but guess what?  But that assertion *also* typically requires an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument; thus all we attain by invoking it without proof is sweeping $\epsilon$-$\delta$ under the rug, as it were.  So I guess what it boils down to is we need to present the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof, or shut up and go home.  Therefore in favor of the former I flesh out the details of the argument I suggested in a comment to the main post:  we use the well-known factorization

$x_2^n - x_1^n = (x_2 - x_1) \left ( \displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} x_2^{n - 1 - k}x_1^k \right ), \tag 7$

which implies

$\vert f(x_2) - f(x_1) \vert = \vert x_2^n - x_1^n \vert  = \vert x_2 - x_1 \vert  \left \vert \displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} x_2^{n - 1 - k}x_1^k \right \vert; \tag 8$

under the assumption that $x_1, x_2 \ge 0$, which is appropriate since we are addressing the case $y > 0$, and hence only need consider $f(x) = x^n$ on $[0, \infty)$, we have

$\left \vert \displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} x_2^{n - 1 - k}x_1^k \right \vert = \displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} x_2^{n - 1 - k}x_1^k; \tag 9$

we now fix $x_1 \in [0, \infty)$ and choose $0 < M \in \Bbb R$ such that

$x_1 < M; \tag {10}$

then if

$0 \le x_2 < M\tag{11}$

as well, we see that

$\displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} x_2^{n - 1 - k}x_1^k < \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} M^{n - 1} = nM^{n - 1}; \tag{12}$

(8) thus yields

$\vert f(x_2) - f(x_1) \vert = \vert x_2^n - x_1^n \vert  \le nM^{n - 1}\vert x_2 - x_1 \vert  ; \tag{13}$

if we now choose any $\epsilon > 0$ and take

$\delta < \min \left \{ \dfrac{\epsilon}{nM^{n - 1}}, M - x_1 \right \}, \tag{14}$

then with

$\vert x_2 - x_1 \vert < \delta \tag{15}$

we have

$-\delta < x_2 - x_1 < \delta, \tag{16}$

or

$x_1 - \delta < x_2 < x_1 + \delta < x_1 + (M - x_1) = M; \tag{17}$

since now $x_1, x_2 < M$ we may apply (13) in concert with (14):

$\vert f(x_2) - f(x_1) \vert < nM^{n - 1} \vert x_2 - x_1 \vert < nM^{n - 1} \dfrac{\epsilon}{nM^{n - 1}} = \epsilon, \tag{18}$

which shows that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x_1$; since $x_1 \in \Bbb R$ is arbitrary, we see that $f(x) = x^n$ is indeed continuous on $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: Hi Robert, the binomial expansion that you have used $(1+y)^n$ is valid only for small $y$, how do you solve this for large values of $y$? Any way its clear that $(1+y)^n>y^n$ but the binomial expansion is what worries me here.

Comment: @s1mple:  do you mean in equation (2)?

Comment: Yes, in equation (2) you might have used binomial expansion it seems to me

Comment: Isn't $(1 + y)^n = 1^n + n \cdot 1^{n - 1} y + \dfrac{n!}{2!(n - 2)!} 1^{n -2} y^2 + \ldots + y^n$ the binomial expansion of $(1 + y)^n$?  (I didn't write out all the terms.)

Comment: yes, but this is applicable for $|y|<1$ right?

Comment: @s1mple:  no it is an algebraic identity valid for all $y$.  Cheers!