# My proof of product of convergent sequences doesn't use square roots

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Motivation: The usual proof of existence of n-roots of reals is rather messy/confusing, so the writter thought it could be easier to prove it using IVT. For this we would have to prove IVT and that $x^n$ is continuous without assuming existence of n-roots of reals in general. The usual proof that if $p_n \to p$  and $q_n \to q$ then $(pq)_n \to pq$ uses square roots, however the writter found a seemingly simple proof of this fact without resorting to square roots, and is therefore suspicious that there could be a mistake.

Lemma: If $|a-b|<\varepsilon$ then $|a|<|b|+\varepsilon$.

Proof: $|a-b|<\varepsilon \iff b-\varepsilon < a < b+\varepsilon \implies -|b|-\varepsilon < a < |b|+\varepsilon \iff |a|<|b|+\varepsilon$.

Remark: The writter doesn't know whether this lemma holds for complex numbers, so decided to do this proof only over real numbers.

Statement: If $s_n \to s$  and $t_n \to t$ then $(sn)_n \to sn$ (over real numbers)

Proof: Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Choose $M_i$ such that $|s_{m_1}-s| <1, |t_{m_2}-t| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2(|s|+1)}$ and $|t_{m_3}-t| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2|t|}$ for $m_i>M_i$, ignoring the last restriction if $|t|=0$. Let $M = \max\{M_i\}$. Then, if $n>M$ and $|t|\neq 0$

$|s_nt_n-st| = |s_n(t_n-t)+t(s_n-s)| \leq |s_n||t_n-t|+|t||s_n-s| < (|s|+1)\frac{\varepsilon}{2(|s|+1)}+|t|\frac{\varepsilon}{2|t|} = \varepsilon$.

If $|t|=0$ this clearly works too. $\square$

Is this proof correct? If yes, can this be used to prove IVT without assuming existence of n-roots, or am i missing something?

Comment: I only know proof by this way can you show the square root method,anyway your method is correct and you can extend this method by just saying that $|p_n|$ is bounded and apply your method

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi it's in Rudin, Principles of Mathematical analysis chapter 3 theorem 3.3, i'm sure you can find it

Comment: I have no idea why you think square-root is needed at all.  The usual proof of limit of products is the product of limits (when exist) doesn't use square-root at all --- just bounded times null is null and convergence implies bounded, together with sum of limits work.

Comment: @user10354138 In a comment of this answer it says that to prove $f(x)=x^n$ is continuous you'd need to assume n-roots are defined, probably the comment is wrong then: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2800920/how-to-proof-the-existence-of-the-nth-roots-using-the-intermediate-value-theorem

Comment: @AnswerMyQuestion I was referring to the now-deleted "The usual proof that if $p_n \to p$  and $q_n \to q$ then $(pq)_n \to pq$ uses square roots"

Comment: the idea of using intermediate vakue theorem is indeed a valid approach, and it's how things are done in Spivak's calculus. But I don't think it's a simpler approach (I think it's a nicer presentation but not necessarily simpler overall) because this requires you to prove the intermediate value theorem which isn't trivial. Anyway the proof of the lemma is (probably) right it's just using the fact bounded times null sequence is null, and is actually quite a standard argument.

Comment: the statement that you **need** existence of nth roots to prove continuity is wrong. You don't need it.